# std::vector of std::function

Tags: function, vector, c++11, visual-c++-2010

I have the following:

```
  typedef std::function<void(const EventArgs&)> event_type;

  class Event : boost::noncopyable
  {
  private:
   typedef std::vector<event_type> EventVector;
   typedef EventVector::const_iterator EventVector_cit;
   EventVector m_Events;

  public:
   Event()
   {
   }; // eo ctor

   Event(Event&& _rhs) : m_Events(std::move(_rhs.m_Events))
   {
   }; // eo mtor

   // operators
   Event& operator += (const event_type& _ev)
   {
    assert(std::find(m_Events.begin(), m_Events.end(), _ev) == m_Events.end());
    m_Events.push_back(_ev);
    return *this;
   }; // eo +=

   Event& operator -= (const event_type& _ev)
   {
    EventVector_cit cit(std::find(m_Events.begin(), m_Events.end(), _ev));
    assert(cit != m_Events.end());
    m_Events.erase(cit);
    return *this;
   }; // eo -=
  }; // eo class Event
```

And during compilation:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(41): error C2451: conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal
1>          Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
```

Now, I understand this is because of what is being stored in the vector and the operator `==`.  Is there another way to store `std::function` in an STL container?  Do I need to wrap it up in something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store `boost::function` in the vector, provided you don't use `std::find`. Since you seem to need this, wrapping the function in its own class with equality would be probably the best.

```
class EventFun
{
  int id_;
  boost::function<...> f_;
public:
  ...
  bool operator==(const EventFun& o) const { return id_==o.id_; } // you get it...
};
```

Note that this requires you maintain the `id_` in a sane way (eg. two different `EventFun`s will have different `id_`s, etc.).

Another possibility would be to store `boost::function`s with a tag the client would remember and use to identify the particular function on deleting it.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I guess my main concern is how to generate that ID on the fly.  I want the readability of using the `+=` to pass a function/lambda in to the event vector.  So I guess the wrapper class needs to generate the ID based on the function passed.  Perhaps the address of it?