# Comparing std::function for member functions

Tags: c++, function, c++11, function-pointers

I tried to search and here similar questions:
[question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847072/comparing-stdfunction)
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833453/comparing-stdfunctions-for-equality)

But anyway, I can't compare member functions. Here's an example:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ClassA a1{};

    function<int(int, int)> f1 = bind(&ClassA::add, a1, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    function<int(int, int)> f2 = bind(&ClassA::add, a1, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);

    cout << boolalpha << "f1 == f2 " << (f1.target_type() == f2.target_type()) << endl; // true
    cout << (f1.target<int(ClassA::*)(int, int)>() == nullptr) << endl; // true

    return 0;
}
```

From the code it's obvious that **f1** and **f2** are different. The first **cout** shows **true** because the types are the same, it's ok. But why the second **cout** is **true**? Why **function::target()** returns **nullptr**?

P.S.: I want to create a simple delegate system so I can pass any function (global, static, member) around. With **std::function** I can add a callback, but I don't know how to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `f1`'s target type is not `int(ClassA::*)(int, int)`. Its target type is going to be the result of that `bind` expression, which on gcc happens to be:

```
std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int (ClassA::*)(int, int)> (
    ClassA, 
    std::_Placeholder<1>, 
    std::_Placeholder<2>)>
```

Which you can see using the ABI demangler:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
// note, the following line technically leaks, but 
// for illustrative purposes only it's fine
cout << abi::__cxa_demangle(f1.target_type().name(), 0, 0, 0) << endl;
```

Note that if the target type was actually a class method, you wouldn't be able to call it with two `int`s - you'd also need the `ClassA*`. For instance, *this* function's target type is `int(ClassA::*)(int, int)`:

```
function<int(ClassA*, int, int)> f3 = &ClassA::add;
```

Comment: `int(ClassA*, int, int)` is not itself a member function type. So the `std::function` target type is not a member function type in that case. This affects the result of the `target` member function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `f3.target_type() == typeid(&ClassA::add)`

Comment: you're right, sorry. what was i thinking. +1 on your comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Those `std::function`s do not hold member functions.  They hold `bind` result types.  As the `bind` is the same pattern of types, the `bind` result types are the same.