# How do I Pass a Member Function to a Function as a Function Pointer?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

Source of Problem https://github.com/claydonkey/PointerToMember/tree/master

Although touched on in [How Can I Pass a **Member Function** to a **Function Pointer**?](/q/4296281), I feel somewhat dissatisfied with the solutions provided, as I don't want to introduce a dependency on the Boost library.

[Comparing **std::function** for **member functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798205/comparing-stdfunction-for-member-functions) is a post that gets close to a solution but ultimately is less optimistic about the use of **std::function** in .
*(it seems that member functions cannot be passed as function pointers)*

**The Problem:**

A function `simpleFunction` which cannot be altered takes a **callback** `pfunc`:

```
typedef int (*FuncPtr_t)(void*, std::pair<int,int>&);
static int simpleFunction(FuncPtr_t pfunc, void *context, std::pair<int,int>& nos)
{
    pfunc(context, nos);
}
```

This function is intended to callback the method `memberFunction` in class `SimpleClass`:

*NB removed void* from original post as it better represents a real world usage.* was `int memberFunction(void*, std::pair<int,int>& nos)`

```
class SimpleClass {
public:  
    int memberFunction(std::pair<int,int>& nos) { return nos.first + nos.second; }
};
```

---

I expected the following to work:

```
MemFuncPtr_t MemFunction = &SimpleClass::memberFunction;
simpleFunction(obj.*MemFunction, nos);
```

but `obj.*MemFunction` has a type: `int (SimpleClass::)(std::pair<int,int>&)`

and it needs to be: `int (*)(std::pair<int,int>&)`

*(wheras `(obj.*MemFunction) (nos);` returns as expected)*

---

I can create and pass a trampoline:

```
int functionToMemberFunction(void* context, std::pair<int,int> & nos) {
     return static_cast<SimpleClass*>(context)->memberFunction(nos);
}
```

and pass it

`simpleFunction(&functionToMemberFunction, &obj, nos);`

but it compiles to around 40 instructions.

---

I can pass a lambda:

```
simpleFunction((FuncPtr_t)[](void* , std::pair<int,int> & nos) {
    return nos.first + nos.second;
}, &obj, nos);
```

That's surprisingly well optimised but a bit ugly and syntactically cumbersome.
*(NB Both  and lambdas require C++11)*

---

I can add a static member to `SimpleClass`:

```
class SimpleClass {
public:  
    int memberFunction(void*, std::pair<int,int>& nos) { return nos.first + nos.second; }
    static int staticFunction(void*, std::pair<int,int> & nos) { return nos.first + nos.second; }
};

FuncPtr_t StaticMemFunction = &SimpleClass::staticFunction;
```

and pass it

`simpleFunction(StaticMemFunction, nullptr, nos);`

and that's just, well ... a static function inside a class.

---

I can use the `<functional>` header:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;

std::function<int(std::pair<int,int>&) > f_simpleFunc = 
std::bind(&SimpleClass::memberFunction, obj, _1);

auto ptr_fun = f_simpleFunc.target<int (std::pair<int,int> & ) >();
```

and try and pass it...

`simpleFunction(*ptr_fun,  nos);`

but ptr_fun reports null.

---

Looking at the x86 assembly - I am at a loss at how memory is addressed, calling a member function (there are an extra 5 instructions [3 `mov`, 1 `lea` and 1 `add`] over the `StaticMemFunction` call). I can only imagine that this is down to locating the class instance in memory and then the function within it.

Comment: Don't spam language tags! C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: A non-static member function needs access to `this`.  You need some way to get that and a regular function pointer does not satisfy that.

Comment: but (obj.*pMemberFunction) (nullptr, nos); produces the correct result...
Sorry for spamming language. The tags were suggested by stackoverflow itself + This is my first posting ever.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass a member function pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130322/how-do-you-pass-a-member-function-pointer)

Comment: Because you passed `obj` as `pMemberFunction`'s `this` parameter in that call.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `std::function`?

Comment: As Jesper said the best option (for c++11) is to use `std::function` with `std::bind`

Comment: tried:
```using  namespace std::placeholders;```
```std::function<int( void *, TwoNumbers&) > f_simpleFunc = std::bind(&SimpleClass::memFunction1, &obj, _1, _2);```
```FuncPtr_t* ptr_fun = f_simpleFunc.target<FuncPtr_t >();```
```simpleFunction(*ptr_fun, nullptr, nos);```
but ```ptr_fun``` returns ```null```

Comment: Jesper + W.F Please could you show me how to use std::Function in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Implement a simple trampoline with a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*FuncPtr_t)(void*, int);
static int simpleFunction(FuncPtr_t pfunc, void *context, int nos)
{
    return pfunc(context, nos);
}

struct A {
    int i;
    int pf(int nos) { std::cout << i << " nos = " << nos << "\n"; return i; }
};

int main() {
    A a { 1234 };
    // could combine the next two lines into one, I didn't.
    auto trampoline = [](void *inst, int nos) { return ((A*)inst)->pf(nos); };
    simpleFunction(trampoline, &a, 42);
}
```

http://ideone.com/74Xhes

I've modified it to consider the assembly:

```
typedef int (*FuncPtr_t)(void*, int);
static int simpleFunction(FuncPtr_t pfunc, void *context, int nos)
{
    return pfunc(context, nos);
}

struct A {
    int i;
    int pf(int nos) { return nos + i; }
};

int f(A& a) {
    auto trampoline = [](void *inst, int nos) { return ((A*)inst)->pf(nos); };
    return simpleFunction(trampoline, &a, 42);
}
```

Compiled with -O3 we get:

```
f(A&):
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    addl    $42, %eax
    ret
```

https://godbolt.org/g/amDKu6

I.e. the compiler is able to eliminate the trampoline entirely.

Comment: Thanks kfsone but isn't that the same as case 3? :
`simpleFunction((FuncPtr_t)[](void* , std::pair<int,int> & nos) {
    return nos.first + nos.second;
}, 0, nos);` _(The "Trampoline" being superflous)_
I think basically it boils down to **Lambda == Solution**

Comment: Sorry I stand corrected as the question posited: the member function must be called inside the lambda. My bad...
"A lambda can only be converted to a function pointer if it does not capture" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer

Comment: kfsone Thanks again. So after a protracted process I finally concluded what you have already suggested. I would like to see the std::function in action at some point, also

Answer (score 2):

All the suggestions have been useful and I think if I collate them all and return to the original problem, I may have a solution that works for me.

---

So I thought a solution would be derived from:

```
simpleFunction(([](void* context,std::pair<int, int> & nos) {
   return nos.first + nos.second; 
}), &obj,  nos);
```

to become:

```
simpleFunction(([&](void* context,std::pair<int, int> & nos) {
   obj.memberFunction(nos);
}), &obj,  nos);
```

right?

error: cannot convert `main()::<lambda(std::pair<int, int>&, void*)> to int (*)(std::pair<int, int>&, void*)`

Lambdas that accept **closures cannot be cast to a function pointer**

> The closure type for a lambda-expression **with no lambda-capture** has a
>   public non-virtual non-explicit const **conversion function to pointer
>   to function** having the same parameter and return types as the closure
>   type’s function call operator. The value returned by this conversion
>   function shall be the address of a function that, when invoked, has
>   the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

This makes sense as function pointers carry no state and this is why `simpleFunction` was gifted with a context pointer `void* context` (like most callbacks!), which is in turn handled by `pFunc`- the function pointer. (*The context being the `SimpleObject` instance `obj` whose member function we wish to delegate to.*)

Ergo a good solution seems to be:

**solution 1**

```
simpleFunction(([](void* context, std::pair<int,int>& n) {
    return static_cast<SimpleClass*>(context)->memberFunction(n);
}), &obj, nos);
```

---

*NB If `obj` is moved from local -> global scope the lambda would not require the object to be passed in at all. but that changes the original problem.*

---

Incredibly, if the member-function has no calls to the class within which it resides, it behaves as a static function, the lambda obviating the need for the class instance

**solution 2**

```
simpleFunction(([](void* context, std::pair<int,int>& n) {
    return static_cast<SimpleClass*>(context)->memberFunction(n);
}), nullptr /* << HERE */, nos); //WILL WORK even though the context is null!
```

This works perfectly as a solution to the original question: the member function indeed does not rely on anything outside the function scope (is this expected C++ behaviour or a happy hack?).

---

In conclusion, in trying to compose a simple analogy to a real world problem I have been naive in my the original question and I really want all the functionality of a **member**-function so solution 1 seems more realistic.
I am little more savvy in distinguishing between member functions and c functions - I spose the clue was in the name **member** (of a class)

*This was all part of a learning experience and the source code including move-semantics solutions is in the link in the original post*.

Answer (score 2):

[std::function<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) plus [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) are a nice way to go. Just capture the `this` in the lambda, an do what you need. You don't event need to write a separate callback if what is being executed is small. Plus `std::function` is required to not need a heap allocation for lambda that only captures a single pointer.

```
class A {
  std::function <void()> notify;
  void someProcessingFunction () {
    // do some work
    if (notify != nullptr)
      notify ();
  }
};

class B {
  void processNotification () {
    // do something in response to notification
  }
};

int main ()
{
  A a;
  B b;

  a.notify = [&b] () { b.processNotification (); };

  a.someProcessingFunction ();
}
```

Comment: nate: it would be great to see an example of std::function or/and std::bind in action.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to pass the object as your callback data, as you do in the first example.  Any overhead is likely a consequence of the calling convention on your target (or perhaps too low a setting on your compiler's optimiser).

Comment: Thanks for the edits Toby.
Are you sure the "trampoline" solution is modern c++?

Answer (score 0):

In these circumstances I use a fusion of your first two methods. That is, I create a trampoline, but make it a `static` function inside the class, to avoid clutter. It does not do what the member function does (as in your second example): it just calls the member function.

Don't worry about a handful of instructions in the calling process. If you ever do need to worry that much about clock cycles, use assembler.

Comment: Surely even the lambda is preferable to the trampoline? (thanks to Toby Speight for the nomenclature "trampoline")

Comment: Yes, of course. The reason I don't use lambdas is that they don't exist in C++, only in C++11. If you can guarantee that every system you ever use your code on will have C++11 on it, then you can use lambdas.